sprinkles are not ok, please help see this overlay - geometry - face overlay,
i am following the donut tutorial, recommended by a nice chap from my last question,
it is great. I have figured out most of problems but this one i cannot find the answer. The sprinkes are red in "face orientation" and i do not know how to fix?
UPDATE: i am adding one more image to explain what i mean, i have fixed problem but only partially, i did select sprinkles and from mesh -> normals -> FLIP. however recalculate inside or outside is not fixing the remaining "red" sprinkles problem.

UPDATE 2: after more research, i finally solved the problem by adding solidify to the long sprinkles. my round sprikles all ok, but the problem was long sprinkles all of them. i added solidify to each one and it fixed. Thanks.

What do you mean by 'face orientation' and what 'last question' are you talking about? The image on the right looks as if something is filtering out any yellow from your image, but without any image of your settings and material node groups it's impossible to say.

Thanks @JohnEason. I have updated my question. Thankyou for blender donut tutorial recommendation. It is a great tutorial.

Hello please share your file

thanks i fixed by adding "solidify" to the problematic mesh aka "long sprinkles" all my round sprinkles all ok, only problem with long sprinkles.

you should be able to fix it with the normals, please share your file if you want us to check

After more research, I finally solved the problem, my round sprinkles were all ok, the problem was long ones, so I added Solidify to each one and it fixed the issue.


Ah ok. I understand the 'Face Orientation' comment now! I thought you were asking about the odd image colour!
